# MySQL REGEXP with ?placeholders how to bind with php variable

Tags: php, mysql

Here is working statement without `?`

```
$query_select_all = "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE CAST(ColumnName AS UNSIGNED) REGEXP '111|114|115'";
$sql = $db->prepare($query_select_all);
$sql->execute();
```

Want to use `'111|114|115'` as php variable (for example `$data`).

Change code to

```
$data = array('111|', '114|', '115');
$query_select_all = "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE CAST(ColumnName AS UNSIGNED) REGEXP (?,?,?)";
$sql = $db->prepare($query_select_all);
$sql->execute($data);
```

`$data` looks like `Array ( [0] => 111| [1] => 114| [2] => 115 )`

After execution of statement get `SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)`.

Suppose something not correct with `$data = array('111|', '114|', '115');`

What is correct code?

Comment: Please print your whole query. What does `$query_select_all_start` contain?

Comment: One moment... will change in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that REGEXP expects only one placeholder, but you are giving it three.

Change this:

```
$sql->execute($data);
```

to:

```
$sql->execute(array('111|114|115'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You give 3 params to regexp while it should be only one:

```
... REGEXP (?,?,?)";
```

So you finally get something like:

```
... REGEXP ('111|','114|','115')";
```

Moreover instead of adding `|` char to some of array elements, you could do something like this:

```
$res = implode('|', $arr);
```

And then just use one param binding in your SQL query.: